# Correct term or phrase for "unidirectional gaga"

Tags: phrases, expressions, slang

I'm not sure if such a figure of speech exists in English, and "unidirectional gaga" is certainly not correct.

But which wording expresses that a person becomes dumber from having exercised/performed something too frequently or in only one particular fashion.

- It's an adverb or phrase that is usually applied to a person. But can also describe activities.
- It primarily expresses "to make stupid" caused by a particular behaviour/performance.
- The persistence or repetetion of past activites is implied to turn the person more dull / less open to alternative approaches.
- Does usually but not necessarily have a derogatory meaning.

Possible alternative ways to express this:

- to become stultified

  - from ingrained habits
  - through monotony
- somebodys behaviour became dull

  - from tedious repetetion
  - ever the same approach

But of course I'm searching for a more catchy phrase or expression which coveres that sentiment.

Comment: Perhaps a cognitive bias would fit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cognitive_biases

Comment: Stefani Germanotta stuck on a conveyor belt?

Answer (score 1):

As for forming a term from it's requirements:

Repititional dumbening?

Comment: 'Repetition fatigue' sounds pleasant.

Comment: +1 I think that's a usable description of the cause and process. But I need to clarify: I'm more looking for a term that describes the final state.

Answer (score 0):

What about *recursively dumber*?